# dql and leftjoin

Tags: doctrine, left-join, dql

I'm trying to create a DQL query with two conditions in a `left join`. It's ok with one condition, but impossible to find the semantic for more conditions. Just below a SQL example about what I'm trying to write in DQL:

```
SELECT 
u.id AS uid,
FROM user u 
LEFT JOIN phonenumber p ON (u.id = p.user_id AND u.status='1')
HAVING COUNT(p.id) > 3
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you [try *ON* and/or *WITH* keywords](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#on-keyword)?

Comment: link is a 404 page…